# How can I fix my C++ includes for QtonPi?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5, qtonpi

I am trying to cross compile my windows/mac/linux application to Qt On Pi 0.2, I have a build environment setup for this purpose and am trying to work my way though its configuration.

However where I have:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
```

it's telling me that it cannot find it unless I change it to:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
```

I don't really want to change all my includes as this is a big application.  What am I missing in my environment setup to cure this?

This is a ubuntu 12.04 32bit setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, someone over at Qt On Pi Mailing list pointed out that I needed to include the:

```
QT += widgets
```

in my qmake project file.

Comment: great, Ubuntu 12.04 running on PI !

Comment: I've retagged Qt5 as this is specifically because of the changes made to the packages in Qt5 which is what the qtonpi project uses, rather than anything to do with the pi

Comment: Keep an eye on [the wiki](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:Developing_with_Qt::Qt-5) until its released with proper documentation.